# database design - MySQL: How to store and split time series

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, time-series

I have a table where I store historical data and add a record for items I'm tracking every 5 mins.
This is an example using just 2 items:

```
+----+-------------+
| id |  timestamp  |
+----+-------------+
|  1 |  1533209426 |
|  2 |  1533209426 |
|  1 |  1533209726 |
|  2 |  1533209726 |
|  1 |  1533210026 |
|  2 |  1533210026 |
+----+-------------+
```

The problem is that I'm actually tracking 4k items and the table keeps getting bigger, also, I don't need 5 mins data if I want to get the last month. What I'm trying to understand is if there's a way to keep 5 mins records for the last 24h, 1h records for the last 7 days etc. Maybe every hour I could get the first 12 records from the 5 mins table and store the average in the 1h table? But what if some records are missing because there were errors? Is this the correct way to solve this problem or there are some better alternatives?

Comment: Have a look at time series databases like influxdb

Comment: @fancyPants I am currently using aws RDS

Comment: Your idea of storing averages every 1 hour (and perhaps every day from the 1 hour table) seems reasonable, you could probably use [triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html) to implement this (and also remove the oldest hour's records from the 5 min table).

Comment: @Nick Thanks, wouldn't setting a trigger for inserted rows cause errors if I stop tracking some items (I've never used triggers)? Something like old entries being still there even though more than 24h passed.

Comment: Yes, the old entries would remain but it should be possible to code around that. Or perhaps set a cron job to clean up old entries. Also, if you stop tracking an item, then you no longer have the worry of the table getting big...

Comment: I have seen a couple products do that (monitoring).  They keep averages of values, with less and less granularity as time goes forward.  It is coded in the application itself, to calculate the averages (SELECT AVG...), delete the data, save the averages into the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track.

There are multiple issues to decide on how to handle -- missing entries, timestamps skewed by 1 second (or whatever), etc.

By providing a count (which *should* always be 12), you can discover some hiccups:

```
SELECT  FLOOR(timestamp / 3600) AS hr,  -- MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED
        COUNT(*),    -- TINYINT UNSIGNED
        AVG(metric)  -- FLOAT
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY 1;
```

Yes, every hour, do the previous hour's worth of data.  Add `WHERE timestamp  BETWEEN ... AND ... + 3599` to constrain the range in question.  Then purge the same set of data.

The table would have `PRIMARY KEY(hr)`.

Unless you are talking about millions of rows in a table, I would not recommend any use of `PARTITION`.